# OxyPlot is not updating title

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot to show a Chart on a user control under WPF/.net 4.5 and have the following XAML:

```
<oxy:Plot x:Name="oxyPlot" Title="{Binding ChartTitle}" Model="{Binding Plot}" />
```

and in my Code-Behind:

```
public string ChartTitle
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ChartTitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChartTitleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartTitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ChartTitle", typeof(string), typeof(ChartControl), new PropertyMetadata("OMICRON Lab Chart"));
```

This property is then set from outside, but OxyPlot seems to ignore any changes to this as soon as a `PlotModel` is assigned. The title supplied via the `PlotModel`s constructor is used, but also changing the property of the model (and calling `RefreshPlot`) does not change the title in the UI.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but now it is working...

I did not change anything about the title, but some other changes must have triggered it to work.

Comment: having the same issue. hope my problem is solved by itself, too.